# describe/sktech a picture of b1((0,0)).

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I have attached an image of the problem I need help with b and c
B i know a circle with a ball centered at the orgin and the set of points less than 1. and c how do i use triangle inequality?

Comment: A picture will *really* help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! A couple of things will improve your question and help it from being closed. First, it's important to explain what you've tried, so people can address replies accordingly. (It's also inappropriate to post your homework verbatim. Instead, please try to ask questions about specific places where you're stuck, or about particular concepts you don't understand.) Second, it's customary (and appreciated) if you [format your answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) instead of posting an image. The [site tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) may be useful, as well.

Answer (score 0):

For part b , consider the ball centered at (x,y) with radius x/2. For the second part of part c, take another point $p$ in the $\delta$-ball and consider the ball with radius half the minimum of the distances $|p-(x,y)|,\delta-|p-(x,y)|$.